# Unresolved reference: pluginManagement

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When I use `pluginManagement` in my `build.gradle.kts`, I get the error "Unresolved reference: pluginManagement". Every other feature that I am using works just fine. I also tried an otherwise empty `build.gradle.kts` with only `pluginManagement {}` at the top-level, but it still fails. The Gradle version is 6.6.1. Same issue for IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) and command line. I cannot find anything helpful. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution right after posting.
From [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management):

> The `pluginManagement {}` block may only appear in either the
> `settings.gradle` file, where it must be the first block in the file, or
> in an [Initialization Script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#init_scripts).